# Queria saber como faz para cada refresh da pagina a .class ser mudada de lugar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Exemplo:
Ordem Normal

```
class 1<br>
class 2<br>
class 3<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
class10<br>
```

---

quero colocar em ordem alatoria a cada refresh
Exemplo:

```
class 3<br>
class 5<br>
class 1<br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
class4<br>
```

As `class` contem imagens e texto
e uma pergunta adicional, vai pesar muito isso?

Comment: Queres que esses elementos com uma classe `.exemplo` sejam re-ordenados a cada vez que a página abra é isso? Porque não fazes isso no servidor?

Comment: existem linhas por exemplo
linha 1 - class 1 - class 2 ....
linha 2 - class 1 - class 2 ...

Comment: assim estao
<div> class1, class2, ....</div>
<div> class1, class2, ....</div>

Comment: Porque não fazes isso no servidor?

Comment: vai ser meu primeiro site, nao sei fazer isso direito rs
se tiveres um link do youtube ou alguma pagina que ajude nisso eu ficaria muito grato :)

Comment: seria algo assim deste género? http://jsfiddle.net/qEM8B/

Comment: sim seria mais ou menos isso sim, porém os 6 dias restante não podem aparecer
obrigado :)
vou testar o jeito do samir

Answer (score 3):

Fiz uma maneira bem simples de se fazer isso. Veja se serve para seu exemplo:

```
$('.item').each(function(i){
      var rdm = Math.floor(Math.random()*$('.item').length-1)
      $(this).before($('.item').eq(rdm));
})
```

No caso, basta mudar a classe `.item` pela desejada. Para deixar somente o primeiro item da *class*, basta fazer isso:

```
$('.item').not('.item:first').hide();
```

#### [Demonstração - JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36a3tdwb/14)

### Outra opção

Ney, me corrija se estiver errado, mas seu propósito me pareceu ser o seguinte: esconder todos os elementos de uma classe, porém deixando a mostra apenas um elemento e que a escolha deste seja aleatória. Caso seja isso mesmo, você pode fazer simplesmente assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rdm = Math.floor(Math.random()*$('.item').length-1)
    $('.item').not($('.item').eq(rdm)).hide();
})
```

#### [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36a3tdwb/13/)

No JsFiddle basta dar um *run* que ele irá mudar a ordem de forma aleatória.

Mas para o que tem na pergunta, vai a primeira opção. E outra coisa, para ter uma melhor visualização retire os `br`.

Comment: esse jeito deu certo, porém preciso ocultar as class restante e deixar só a primeira class a mostra,
obs.: desculpem por nao ter explicado isso antes

Comment: aí é sacanagem hein @Ney.. rsrs.. então qual a finalidade do `.<br>.<br>.<br>` ?

Comment: @Ney , fiz uma edição com o que você precisa.

Comment: bom pessoal, sou novato rs, mas com ajuda de vcs fiz assim e deu certinho:

$('div1 > .class1, div1 > .class2, div1 > .class3').each(function(i){
      var rdm = Math.floor(Math.random()*$('div1 > .class1, div1 > .class2, div1 > .class3').length-1)
      $(this).before($('div1 > .class1, div1 > .class2, div1 > .class3').eq(rdm));
}) 

    $('div1 > div:first').show();

Class{Display:none}

Obrigado a todos :)

Comment: ok vou aceitar, obrigado samir :)

Comment: @Ney, de nada. Fico feliz em ter ajudado..

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo com JQuery:

```js
$().ready(function() {
 str = ".<br>.<br>.<br>";
 e = $("#content").find($("br"));
 p = Math.floor((Math.random() * e.length));
 l = e.length - 1;
 //console.log(e.length, p, l);
 $.each(e, function(key, val){
  //console.log("key "+key, "v: "+val);
  if (key == p)
   (key == l)? $(this).prev().after(str) : $(this).after(str);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
class 1<br>
class 2<br>
class 3<br>
class 4<br>
</div>
```

Procurei fazer algo que fosse menos invasivo possível, ou seja, que não precisasse modificar o código atual.

Para facilitar é preciso apenas colocar o conteúdo dentro de uma `<div>` com um ID, para que o JQuery saiba onde pegar os elementos.

Note também que o script tem o cuidado de identificar a posição retornada da randomicidade. A lógica base é adicionar elementos, porém, quando a posição for último `<br>` (class4), os elementos ficariam na parte posterior. Por isso, quando a posição for a penúltima ou a última, sempre resultará em

```
class 1<br>
class 2<br>
class 3<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
class 4<br>
```

Caso queira trocar esse comportamento, apenas modifique a condicional:

```
(key == l)? $(this).prev().after(str) : $(this).after(str);
```

Troque por isso:

```
$(this).after(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas tecnicas para embaralhar um array, a minha predileta faz uso do `Array.protorype.sort` com `Math.random()`.

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = function () {
  return this.sort(function () {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
  });
}
```

```js
var tmplItem = document.getElementById("tmplItem").content;
for (var indice = 1; indice <= 20; indice++) {
  var card = document.importNode(tmplItem, true).querySelector(".card");
  document.body.appendChild(card);
  
  var text = card.querySelector(".content span");
  card.classList.add("class" + indice);
  text.textContent = "Item " + indice;
}

Array.prototype.shuffle = function () {
  return this.sort(function () {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
  });
}

//transformar uma NodeList em Array.
var cards = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".card"));

//Embaralhando o Elementos e reinserindo os eles na pagina.
cards.shuffle().forEach(function (card, item) {  
  document.body.appendChild(card);
});
```

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 128px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
  
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
  background-color: white;
}

.card .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  
  background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/34/34239.svg');
  background-size: calc(100% - 10px);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-right: 1px solid gainsboro;
}

.card .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 128px;
  
}

.card .content span {
  line-height: 88px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card .menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 128px;
  border-top: 1px solid gainsboro;
}
```

```html
<template id="tmplItem">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="icon">

    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```